# Javadoc overview.html: embedded link yields blank frame

Tags: javadoc

I have the following code in an overview.html file.

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
    Evermore is a trip planning app which can create and execute multiple searches
    and present the results all on a single map.
    <p>
    Test link: <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>.
    <p>
    Test link: <a href="http://github.com/barryholroyd/Evermore/wiki/Architecture">Evermore Architecture</a>.
</body>
```

The file displays just fine. However, when I click on the embedded *Evermore Architecture* link it yields a blank frame. Ditto with the *Google* link.

Is there a solution/workaround for this?

Thanks,
Barry